# How to get the event id while DEM reads snapshot data ? [autosar][vector]

Tags: autosar

How to get the event id while DEM reads snapshot data ? [autosar][vector]

I don't get the event id for corresponding shanpshot read DID function call.

Comment: "I don't get the event id" So what do you get instead? And how did you try to get it?

Comment: Why would the EventId be from importance, when the Dem reads the snapshot data DID by DID? The DID is a unique "Data Identifier" describing a specific data element in your software, which can be added to different snapshot records of different DemEvents, and even can have RDBI, WDBI, IOCBI services.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the DEM specification container *DemDataElementUsePort* is boolean type. But if you use MICROSAR (Vector) this option is enum and it allows to configure interface for this specific *DemDataElementClass* as port or function with additoinal EventId parameter.

[Dem containers hierarchy for snapshot data configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fYq7.png)